# How to concate the Currency symbol for negative integers?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to show the currency symbol with the numbers. I am using the **CONCAT** method to do this.

```
select concat('$', "amount") from payments;
```

This method working good when the amount is positive but when the amount is negative it is concat the currency symbol before minus.

eg: 
 **$-243.44**

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select case`

```
select case when amount < 0 then concat('-$', abs("amount")) else concat('$', "amount") end from payments;
```

Comment: -$-79.20 it is fetching like this.

Comment: added abs() function

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you take advantage of Postgres' in-built currency type, e.g.

```
SELECT '-243.44'::float8::numeric::money;
```

This printed `-£243.44` on the demo tool I am using, which appears to be located in the UK.  The actual currency symbol you see would depend on your Postgres locale settings.

If you really need to do this concatenation yourself, you could use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT '-123.456'::text AS val UNION ALL
    SELECT '123.456'::text
)

SELECT
    val,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '^(-?)', '\1$') AS val_out
FROM cte;
```

Comment: I am dynamically adding the currency symbol infront of integers. Like, for the usa payments I have to add "$", for the India payments i have to add "Rs."

Comment: @MenporulPoriyalan Try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` in this case.